# Generate string for excel sheet

Tags: javascript, excel, ascii

I'm trying to generate a string, which can be pasted in excel and will be arranged correctly as a table

I'm using `tabs` to separate columns and `CRLF` to separate rows

```js
import values from 'lodash/values'
const toExcelString = matrix =>
    matrix
        .map(row => values(row).join('\t'))
        .join(`\r\n`)
```

Generates this string:

```js
2016-12-01 00:00:00 0 3000 0 0 0 0 3000
2017-01-03 00:00:00 1 0 0 196.66 113.92 310.58 2803.34
2017-02-01 00:00:00 2 0 0 217.03 93.55 310.58 2586.31
2017-03-01 00:00:00 3 0 0 227.25 83.33 310.58 2359.06
2017-04-03 00:00:00 4 0 0 221 89.58 310.58 2138.06
2017-05-01 00:00:00 5 0 0 241.69 68.89 310.58 1896.37
2017-06-01 00:00:00 6 0 0 242.93 67.65 310.58 1653.44
2017-07-03 00:00:00 7 0 0 249.7 60.88 310.58 1403.74
2017-08-01 00:00:00 8 0 0 263.74 46.84 310.58 1140
2017-09-01 00:00:00 9 0 0 269.91 40.67 310.58 870.09
2017-10-02 00:00:00 10 0 0 279.54 31.04 310.58 590.55
2017-11-01 00:00:00 11 0 0 290.19 20.39 310.58 300.36
2017-12-01 00:00:00 12 0 0 300.36 10.37 310.73 0
```

But when I paste it in excel (2016) it appears as one cell. What am I doing wrong?

I also tried to add `CRLF` in the and, and using `String.fromCharCode` in stead of `\t` and `\r\n`

Also I'm using [copy-to-clipboard](https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-to-clipboard) library.

Comment: *"Generates this string..."* - works for me in Excel 2013...

Comment: That's a thing, if I paste it to other editor and then paste it in excel, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's not your excel settings that is causing the issues?

Check out this link: 
http://www.wikihow.com/Copy-Paste-Tab-Delimited-Text-Into-Excel